# what's the meaning of "class CLASS_EXPORT IKLogin_Export"

Tags: c++, class, interface

I know the base usage to define a interface class, but I have not seen code as follows. Why there is CLASS_EXPORT? What's its meaning?

```
class CLASS_EXPORT IKLogin_Export {

...
}
```

Comment: It indicates this interface class can be exported to dll.

Comment: You can [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), which can help take your question off the unanswered questions list.

Answer (score 0):

It indicates this interface class can be exported to dll.